# "invalid syntax" thrown upon defining a variable

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

```
import math as m

a = 6378137.0
c = 6356752.314245
e = m.sqrt( 1 - ((c**2)/(a**2))
s = 2 * (m.pi) * ( a**2 ) * ( 1 + ( ( ( 1 - ( e**2 ) ) / e ) ) * (m.atanh( e )) )

print( s )
```

my code is throwing an invalid syntax error on line 6, when I try to define the `s` variable.

Comment: This code is not a minimal standalone example. For instance, what is `m`?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a close-parenthesis on line 5.

Comment: Thanks, I counted them about ten times before I gave up and posted here. My blind trust in your advice fixed it.

Comment: Sometimes it's that simple

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parentheses on **line 5**. Compare with this code:

```
from math import *

a = 6378137.0

c = 6356752.314245

e = sqrt( 1 - ((c**2)/(a**2)))

s = (2 * (pi) * ( a**2 ) * ( 1 + ( ( ( 1 - ( e**2 ) ) / e ))) * (atanh( e )) )

print( s )
```

In other words, you need to add a " ) " at the **end of line 5**. I hope that helps. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.